# JavaScript: How to modify value in <option>

Tags: javascript

How do I modify a value of `<option>`?

I've tried:

```
var example = document.getElementById("test"); // This is the <option>  
example.value = "Test";
```

The code above doesn't modify anything.
However, if the code above modifies a value of `<select>`'s displayed value, the value goes blank;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `example.textContent` to change the value that's displayed. The value that is displayed when an `option` element is selected is its text content.

However, as indicated in Oriol's answer, changing the value property is meaningful, even if it is not immediately visible.

```js
document.getElementById("change").onclick = function () {
    var option = document.getElementById("test");
    option.textContent = "bon soir";
    option.value = "les étoiles sont belles, hein?";
}

document.getElementById("selector").onchange = function() {
    // in this line "this" refers to the <select> element
    document.getElementById("selection").textContent = this.value;
}
```

```html
<select id="selector">
    <option></option>
    <option id="test" value="good to see you">hello</option>
    <option value="see you again">goodbye</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="change" value="Change value" />
<div id="selection"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to add a code snippet now that I just found this new feature +1 Note, value does get used, it's the value that gets sent to server when you submit the form, but the content of the option tag is what gets displayed

Answer (score 0):

The `value` of an option and its text are different things.

Its `value` will become, when selected, the `value` of the `select`, and will be sent to the server when submitting the form. Analogously, when you set `select`'s value, the selected `option` will be the one that has that `value`.

What you want to change is its text, e.g. with one of these:

```
option.textContent = "Test";
option.innerHTML = "Test";
```

Answer (score 0):

In realy, you need to see how option element sintax.

```
<option value="my_value">The Label</option>
```

So, you need to change the textContent instead value. See the sample below.

```js
document.getElementById('change').onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('my_option').textContent = 'My New Label';
  document.getElementById('my_option').value = 'my_new_value';
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option id="my_option" value="my_value">My Label</option>
</select>

<button id="change" type="button">change</button>
```

The first changes the label (a nicename for the user) and the second changes the value sended to server.